# How to stop Node sequelize logging status

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm using npm package `sequelize` + `mysql` and then:

```
let option = {logging: false}
```

While initializing:

```
new Sequelize(option)
```

**It works *fine* for not outputting the query string.**

However, it is still outputting the status code after I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the database, and the result look like this: `[ undefined, 1 ]`, `[3 , 1]`(3 is the id, `[AffectedID, AffectedRow]`)

I believe I need to change the `cursor` settings, but I found none.

I'm following the instructions, so the code is basically very similar to : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/usage.html

I'm using the RAW query and here is my query sentence:

```
.query(query, {
      replacements: parameters,
      type: Sequelize.QueryTypes[qt]
    })
```

So how can I stop this ? Should I change mysql settings directly or there is a better way ?

**EDIT:**

I just found out I had a auto-logger and I need to set it to false for insert and update, so thanks for the reply.

Comment: That doesn't seem like logging but something else. Can you show some code that generates that output?

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating sequelize takes in more parameters than just the options object. You need to also pass your `database`, `username`, and `password` before your config options.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  logging: false
  // rest of your config
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There another way to stop logging of sequelize query. just add extra key named `"logging": false,` of your sequelize config file.
here is example

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "xxx",
    "password": "",
    "database": "xxx",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "operatorsAliases": false,
    "timezone" : "+06:00"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "xxx",
    "password": "xxx,
    "database": "xxxx",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "timezone" : "+06:00"
  },
  "production": {
    "logging": false,
    "username": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxx",
    "database": "xxx",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "timezone" : "+06:00"
  }
}
```

Its highly suggested to you to configure logging status from here, by this you can control your logging. cause production database should not showing log but production and test database should to showing log.

Answer (score 1):

Besides @Trevor's answer is a good answer, Changing the **logging** on runtime cannot be achieved via his answer.

His answer turned off the logging whenever `Sequelize` instance is created. But what about changing the logging on runtime. Say i want to turn off logging in few cases. To achieve that

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  logging: false
  // rest of your config
});

// your logging is turned off


// Somewhere else you 
sequelize.options.logging = true


// Somewhere else you want logging to be turned off again
sequelize.options.logging = true
```

[Reference](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/edac3e9075f9daf70a9ae0681dd4a847db5cbc59/lib/sequelize.js#L240) From the source.

This behavior is quiet useful while development and run test on your code base. In development you want to see all logs, but in automated testing environment you are mainly interested in test results.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: after I initialize Sequelize like `const db = new Sequelize({ options })` I try to write `db.options` and there is no `options` property on it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to disable logging for a specific query:

```
const userProfileByCredentials = await Models.users.findOne({where: {email, password}, logging: false});
```